# What powers an LED across an open switch?

Tags: led, switches, light

Honestly, I just can’t seem to figure out how this switch works.

I have a light switch that incorporates an LED that is on when the light is off. The neutral is not connected to the switch. The switch has only two wires: live in and out.

What powers the LED?

This is taken from the wiring diagram:
[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: You haven’t asked a specific question. However, dimmers and some switches ‘bleed’ a couple of milliamperes when switched off, which is enough to light a LED but not enough for a filament lamp.

Answer (score 0):

It would put the LED + resistor in series with the load when 'off'. The current through the LED + resistor is so small the load is practically off. The LED + resistor is shorted with the switch contact to turn the load on.

Note that if the load is particularly sensitive it may not actually turn off completely. For example, an LED bulb might emit dim flashes periodically or that sort of thing.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0jmX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You haven’t asked a specific question.  However, dimmers and some switches ‘bleed’ a couple of milliamperes when switched off, which is enough to light a LED but not enough for a filament lamp.

Comment: @Frog I believe you have added your comment in the wrong place.  Shouldn't it be connected to the question rather than an answer?

Comment: @HandyHowie you’re right, thank you.

Comment: So if i’m understanding correctly, + is converted to -?

Comment: The current goes through the load and the LED and resistor. I've guessed that the LED may be a bipolar type (two junctions inside one plastic package) but it could be something else. That way each LED die emits light on alternate half-cycles (and protects the other die from excessive reverse voltage).